# Slow GIF animations in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, performance, animated-gif

Anyone experiencign slow GIF animations in Firefox 3.5.3, Mac OSX 10.5.8 ? They tend to slow whole page scrolling, but when viewed as single animations, they run smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

Disable "Use Smooth Scrolling" in the advanced options under the General tab.

If it's already unchecked I would report a performance bug to Mozilla unless your computer is very underpowered.

Comment: I’ve done some research on similar topics and it could be possibly related to Firefox scroll lagging, but I don’t know if it’s OSX specific or it happens on every OS.

Comment: My old laptop used to lag while scrolling if this option was on and it was a Windows XP machine. I don't think it's OS X specific.

Answer (score 0):

Slow is too much relative thing, but looks like that gif animation is slower in FF than in Chrome and even IE 8. All these on Windows XP.